# Gröbner–Shirshov basis for free Lie algebras

Tags: combinatorics, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

I have already studied several papers related to composition-diamond lemma completely and now I am familiar with theoretical tools. For instance I realized the concept of associative Lyndon–Shirshov words, non-associative Lyndon–Shirshov words and their properties plus necessary lemmas and theorems.

Now I would like to utilize those theoretical tools for a small example. May you please  help me to find an effective example of a free Lie algebras to construct a Gröbner–Shirshov basis?